# Using class instead of ID for HTML5-canvas animation cause js-error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, canvas

So I have made an animation with Animate CC, and exported it to a HTML5-canvas.
No I want to use the animation in multiple canvases based on class. It works fine when calling the ID, however only the first `#ovals-bg` has a rendered animation. My guess is that `createjs-2015.11.26.min.js` is calling stuff via the `ID`. Is there something I can do in my custom.js-file to fix this?

Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Lumiere TEST</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lumiere.css">
        <script type='text/javascript' src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js?ver=4.2.7"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="js/includes/animatioj.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src="js/custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4;margin:0px;">
        <div id="wrap">
            <ul class="lumeiere-thumbs cf">
                <li class="thumb">
                    <canvas class="squares" class="canvas" width="510" height="510" style="background-color:none"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="ovals-bg" class="canvas ovals-bg" width="510" height="510" style="background-color:none"></canvas>
                </li>
                <li class="thumb">
                    <canvas class="squares" class="canvas" width="510" height="510" style="background-color:none"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="ovals-bg" class="canvas ovals-bg" width="510" height="510" style="background-color:none"></canvas>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

custom.js:

```
function init() {

    // ovalsBG = document.getElementById("ovals-bg"); <--- This works fine
    ovalsBG = document.getElementsByClassName("ovals-bg");
    ovalsBG_Root = new lib.ovalsBG();

    ovalsBG_stage = new createjs.Stage(ovalsBG);
    ovalsBG_stage.addChild(ovalsBG_Root);
    ovalsBG_stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", ovalsBG_stage);

}
```

JS-error:

[image]

---

**EDIT 1:**

> So I tried the edits suggested below like this:

```
 ovalsBG = document.getElementsByClassName("ovals-bg");
        ovalsBG_Root = new lib.ovalsBG();


        for (i = 0; i < ovalsBG.length; i++)  {
            /* ovalsBG_stage = new createjs.Stage(ovalsBG); <-- this renders nothing */
            ovalsBG_stage = new createjs.Stage(ovalsBG[i]); /* <-- this renders one stage in the second class-item. */
            ovalsBG_stage.addChild(ovalsBG_Root);
            ovalsBG_stage.update();

            createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
            createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", ovalsBG_stage);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I Finally got it working usign @theblindprophet's snippet below:

```
function init() {

    //ovalsBG = document.getElementById("ovals-bg");

    ovalsBG = document.getElementsByClassName("ovals-bg");



    for (i = 0; i < ovalsBG.length; i++)  {

        ovalsBG_Root = new lib.ovalsBG();
        ovalsBG_stage = new createjs.Stage(ovalsBG[i]);
        ovalsBG_stage.addChild(ovalsBG_Root);
        ovalsBG_stage.update();

        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", ovalsBG_stage);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you have 2 canvas elements that have the same id. Ids must be **unique**. This would be why only the first element with the specified id is working because `getElementById` only returns the first match. And also declare all your classes for an elements under the same class attribute (`class=""`), there is no reason to declare more than one.

Second, when you set a variable to a class selector that variable then becomes an array of all the elements with the class and that is why you cannot use the canvas because you are trying to use an array instead of a single selection.

If you decide to use the array the you simply need:

```
for(i = 0; i < ovalsBG.length; i++) {
    // perform canvas stuf here
    // ovalsBG[i].dowhatever
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know the ID-stuff, was just a bit sloppy with my code :)
Well the thing is I want to re-use the same animation for multiple canvases, I'll be doing everything in php later on so maybe I could use variables to increment ID-names?

Comment: You can use class names, but then iterate through the array returned using a loop

Answer (score 0):

The `getElementsByClassName()` API returns collection like `object` Which is essentially like an `Array` of `DOM Objects`. And `getElementById()` API returns a `DOM Object`.

If you change your code to

`ovalsBG = document.getElementsByClassName("ovals-bg")[0];`

it will work fine.

However, be advised that this will only work for FIRST element that has a class `ovals-bg`.

UPDATE:

Since I have no idea what these `lib.ovalsBG` and `createjs.Stage` classes stand for, I'll go with the beacon that may solve your problem

```
function init() {
    ovalsBG = document.getElementsByClassName("ovals-bg");
    ovalsBG_Root = new lib.ovalsBG();
    for(var elem in ovalsBG){
        var ovalsBG_stage = new createjs.Stage(ovalsBG[elem]);
        ovalsBG_stage.addChild(ovalsBG_Root);
        ovalsBG_stage.update();

        createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", ovalsBG_stage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, with that sollution I might as well use ID...

The lib.ovalsBG calls the animation (ovalsBG is name of the function) generated by Animate CC. The createjs.Stage also comes from the Animate CC-export. Not sure there.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining your code

```
 ovalsBG = document.getElementsByClassName("ovals-bg");
```

Returns your array of elements, But your requirement is to get single element. So access that single element by using index. Assuming you need the first element in the array you can use this code

```
 ovalsBG = document.getElementsByClassName("ovals-bg")[0]; // note the [0]
```

---

Since the question is tagged with `jquery` why dont you keep it simple like this.

```
 ovalsBG = $("ovals-bg:eq(0)"); //eq(0) takes the first element
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

> Well the thing is I want to re-use the same animation for multiple canvases

according to this comment. you can do this to apply the same animation to multiple canvas with the same class name.

```
function init() {
   $('.ovals-bg').each(function(){      
     ovalsBG = $(this);
     ovalsBG_Root = new lib.ovalsBG();

     ovalsBG_stage = new createjs.Stage(ovalsBG);
     ovalsBG_stage.addChild(ovalsBG_Root);
     ovalsBG_stage.update();

     createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
     createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", ovalsBG_stage);
    });           
}
```